# Why doesn't hijacking a crate count towards my kills or destroys in the Care Package Killstreak Challenge?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I am having an issue with the Care Package Killstreak Challenge.  When I hijack a crate and someone takes it, it doesn't count towards my kills or destroys. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Kills with a care package can be obtained in two ways:
(1) Dropping it on their heads, which is hilarious and awesome, but really hard to do on purpose.
(2) Hacking an enemy care package using the 'Hacker' perk. When they go back to get it, they will think it is still theirs but it will explode upon them taking it. I have seen someone get 7 kills with one this way, although that was because the other team was stupid.
Good luck and happy dropping!

Answer (score 1):

To get a destroys for the Care Package Killstreak, you must shoot down the helicopter that brings it in. (Use the strela)

To get kills with it, I believe you must call one in and have it land on an opponent, killing them.

I am not sure about the kills though, feel free to correct me.